# Slick table not saved in DB with no errors

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

i am using slick 3.2.3 with Scala Play framework 2.6. 
I'm inserting   rows to table with iteration . Some time it save  successfully ,but  some time it save few rows  in MYSQL (Some rows are missing ) . what might be root cause ?
MYSQL version - 5.7
this is my code

```
try {
      db.run {
        documentDetails.map(p => (p.documentDetailsId, p.documentDirectoryId, p.patentId, p.hospitalId, p.clinicId, p.patientType, p.categoryType, p.admissionAppointmentNo, p.documentName, p.status, p.remarks, p.description)) += (docId, documentDirectoryId, patentId, hospitalId, clinicId, patientType, categoryType, admissionAppointmentNo, documentName, true, remarks, description)
      }
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        e.printStackTrace()
        logger.error(e.getMessage)
        throw e
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.run` returns a `Future` so you should do something with this `Future`.

By the way, your `try-catch` block doesn't check if the future is failed.

Try

```
Await.result(db.run(...), Duration.Inf)
```

if blocking is ok for you (this depends on where this code is).

Comment: i get Future  Success(1) while im debugging. i think slick not commit to the database . any idea to fix that ?
same with Await(blocking).

Comment: Where is this code? In `main` method, in some Play controller etc.?

Comment: yes Async controller .i tried with batch insert ( ++= )as well not working.

Comment: Can you try to run your code with db.run from main method? (In order to know if the issue is with slick or controller)

Comment: i execute db.run on main controller then it save perfectly fine. but execute through Dao class it miss some rows . not solved yet.

Comment: Does this mean that the issue is not with Slick but with Play/controller?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's best to check the **rowsAffected** ... in either DBIO or Future, ej(s):

Docs: (**rowsAffected**)

```
/** Insert multiple rows, skipping AutoInc columns.
      * Uses JDBC's batch update feature if supported by the JDBC driver.
      * Returns Some(rowsAffected), or None if the database returned no row
      * count for some part of the batch. If any part of the batch fails, an
      * exception is thrown. */
    def ++= (values: Iterable[U]): ProfileAction[MultiInsertResult, NoStream, Effect.Write]
```

Therefore in DBIO:

```
      /**
        *
        * @param f function throws exception
        * @return DBIO.successful --> is good!!!
        *         DBIO.failed(th) --> is bad :-(
        */
      def validate(f: => Unit): DBIOAction[Unit, NoStream, Effect] = try {
        DBIO.successful(f)
      } catch {
        case NonFatal(th) => DBIO.failed(ValidationError(th))
      }

      def checkRowsAffected(rowsAffect: Int, rowsAffected: Int,
        errorMessage: String = "rowAffected not equal rowsAffect"): DBIOAction[Unit, NoStream, Effect] =
        validate(require(rowsAffect == rowsAffected, errorMessage))

      val BannersInsertQuery = Banners returning Banners.map(_.id)

       for {
           bannersInserted <- BannersInsertQuery ++= bannersToInsert
           _ <- checkRowsAffected(bannersToInsert.length, bannersInserted.length)
       } yield bannersInserted
```

Therefore in Future:(Using db.run)

```
/**
    *
    * @param f function throws exception
    * @return Future.successful --> is good!!!
    *         Future.failed(ex) --> is bad :-(
    */
  def validate(f: => Unit)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = Future.successful(f).recover {
    case ve: ValidationError => Future.failed(ve)
    case NonFatal(th)        => Future.failed(ValidationError(th))
  }

  def checkRowsAffected(rowsAffect: Int, rowsAffected: Int,
                        errorMessage: String = "rowAffected not equal rowsAffect")
                       (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] =
    validate(require(rowsAffect == rowsAffected, errorMessage))


db.run(BannersInsertQuery ++= bannersToInsert).map( bannersInserted => checkRowsAffected(bannersToInsert.length, bannersInserted.length))
```